# MDX CASE Statement in EXCEL

Tags: excel, mdx, olap

I am accessing a data in an OLAP cube in excel and trying to use an MDX query to create a new calculated measure in my PivotTable.

Based on the container size I need to calculate the capacity for that specific container size.

I am using a CASE Statement, however my query is ignoring all the WHEN clauses and using the ELSE clause.

```
CASE 
WHEN [CONTAINER INSTANCE DIMENSION].[Container Size] = '20' THEN ([Measures].[Ocean Container COUNT]*33)
WHEN [CONTAINER INSTANCE DIMENSION].[Container Size]  = '20H' THEN ([Measures].[Ocean Container COUNT]*40)
WHEN [CONTAINER INSTANCE DIMENSION].[Container Size]  = '40H' THEN ([Measures].[Ocean Container COUNT]*69)
WHEN [CONTAINER INSTANCE DIMENSION].[Container Size]  = '40R' THEN ([Measures].[Ocean Container COUNT]*56)
ELSE ([Measures].[Ocean Container COUNT]*56)
END
```

For example: the 20Ft containers sum up to 128 therefore the capacity is supposed to be 4224 (128*33); however I am getting 7168(128*56).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following change. Instead of

```
WHEN [CONTAINER INSTANCE DIMENSION].[Container Size] = '20'
```

you need to write

```
WHEN [CONTAINER INSTANCE DIMENSION].[Container Size].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION = '20'.
```

In your query you want to select your multiplier based on the value of container size. To get the value that is being evaluated at the moment, we use "Currentmember". Plus you are checking the "MEMBER_CAPTION" property of your CURRENTMEMBER.The way you are checking the value will not work. MDX will evaluate

```
[CONTAINER INSTANCE DIMENSION].[Container Size] = '20'
```

to true, since you are evaluating a dimension attribute against a value. Hence your Else clause gives the result.

Below is a sample on AdventureWorks.

```
with member 
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountCase]
as
case 
when [Product].[Size].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION = '38' then [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]*1
when [Product].[Size].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION = '40' then [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]*2
when [Product].[Size].CurrentMember.MEMBER_CAPTION = '46' then [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]*3
else -99
end

select 
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountCase]}
on columns,

([Date].[Month of Year].[Month of Year],[Product].[Size].[38]:[Product].[Size].[70])
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Results:[image]

Comment: @Javaine did the above sample help?